# Returning non-alphanumeric characters found by REGEX

Tags: r, regex

I have no problem finding and returning words containing non-alphanumeric characters, but what I'd like to do is return the non-alphanumeric character that was found.  For example:

```
a <- c("hello?", "goodbye","hi!")
grep("[^[:alnum:]]", a, value=TRUE)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "hello?" "hi!"
```

But what I'd like to return is:

```
[1] "?" "!"
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

EDIT:  I love this...two user responses, four different ways to get it done.  I've learned a lot.  Thank you!

Comment: @Cath Minor revision: `gsub("[[:alnum:]]", "", grep("[^[:alnum:]]", a, value=TRUE))` or `gsub("[[:alnum:]]", "", a[grepl("[^[:alnum:]]", a)])`.

Comment: @lmo, thank you, great ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to remove the alphanumeric characters by matching the pattern (`[^[:punct:]]+` - meaning one or more non punctuation characters) and replace it with blanks (`""`).  We remove the blanks either with `nzchar` or `setdiff`.

```
setdiff(gsub("[^[:punct:]]+", "", a), "")
#[1] "?" "!"
```

---

Or another option is `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
as.vector(na.omit(str_extract(a, "[[:punct:]]+")))
#[1] "?" "!"
```